# Google Map Geofence - Draw Rectangle

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, gis, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to create Rectangle Geo-fence using Google Map API Reference. Using this API I am getting :

1. North-East Latitude & Longitude
2. South-West Latitude & Longitude

But for my Project I want all the 4 Vertex Lat. & Long. Co-ordinates. Please help me to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have NE, SW

```
 North-East Latitude & Longitude = north_lat, east_lng 
 South-West Latitude & Longitude = south_lat, west_lng
```

you have the rect coord ..

in pseudo code

```
rectangle coord  = (north_lat, west_lng)  
                   (north_lat, east_lng)
                   (south_lat, east_lng) 
                  ( south_lat, west_lng) 
 or using eg: the coords

 var bounds = {
   north: 44.599,
   south: 44.490,
   east: -78.443,
   west: -78.649
};
```

you can use rectangle

```
rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
  bounds: bounds
});
```